# Get current device synced account

Tags: intune

I have my computer connected to Microsoft MDM InTune. I need to get with powershell, wmi or any other tool, the current device synced account.

I'm trying to use wmi with this class: "ROOT\CIMV2\mdm\dmmap:MDM_ActiveSync_User_Accounts01_01", but there is no instance.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: did you find any workarounds?